# Having problems with my function in C trying to calculate a Regression slope using lesser block method. Can anyone help me figure out my mistake?

Tags: c, math

This is C, can't use anything but C.

So I was given the equation here:

[image]

I am trying to calculate the 'b' in the formulae. The formula is Regression slope done via Lease Squares Formulae

My code takes in a list of numbers called 'arr[]' and the amount of elements in that list being 's'. I go through the calculations and I get the wrong number. If anyone can help me out that would be awesome and if I'm not allowed to ask this here, please point me in the direction to where I can ask this.

calcMean is a function that calculates the mean.
An Example of what I need:
With a list of numbers being: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 7
I need to get a: 0.429
My code currently gives me an answer that is quite off.

My code:

```
double calcRegSlope(double arr[], int s) {
    double result = 0.0;
    double meanX = 0.0;
    double meanY = 0.0;
    double sumX = 0.0;
    double sumY = 0.0;
    double xValue = 0.0;
    double yValue = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        sumX += pow((double)i,2.0);    
        sumY += (arr[i] * (double)i);
        meanX += (double)i;
    }
    
    meanX = meanX / (double)s;
    meanY = calcMean(arr, s);
    
    
    xValue = sumX - (s * pow(meanX, 2.0));                            
    yValue = sumY - (s * meanX * meanY);                            
    
    result = yValue / xValue;
    
    return (double)result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the wrong number"?  What are you comparing it to?  What do you actually get?  Perhaps it is something trivial like x_i == i - 1 or x_i == i +1, but I don't think enough information has been given to determine that.

Comment: Try giving your program a simple example, where you know the answer and can do the calculations manually. Then check the intermediate results of your program, and compare them to intermediate results which you calculated manually. This will show where your error is. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have not given the implementation of the `calcMean(arr, s)` function, I am assuming that you are able to implement it without any logical errors.

The problem I sense here is that the summation in the least squares formula is from `i = 1` till `i = n`. But you have looped from `i = 0` till `i=n-1`.

Here you just need to run the loop from `i = 1` till `i = s` and access `arr` elements through as `arr[i-1]`.

Try this code with the change implemented and let me know if the error still persists.

```
double calcRegSlope(double arr[], int s) {
    double result = 0.0;
    double meanX = 0.0;
    double meanY = 0.0;
    double sumX = 0.0;
    double sumY = 0.0;
    double xValue = 0.0;
    double yValue = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
        sumX += pow((double)i,2.0);    
        sumY += (arr[i-1] * (double)i);
        meanX += (double)i;
    }
    
    meanX = meanX / (double)s;
    meanY = calcMean(arr, s);
    
    
    xValue = sumX - (s * pow(meanX, 2.0));                            
    yValue = sumY - (s * meanX * meanY);                            
    
    result = yValue / xValue;
    
    return (double)result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get the right answer. With a list of numbers being:
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 7
I need to get a: 0.429
And with the code above I get a: 0.495

Comment: @KadenDavila This is the answer that I got after doing it manually. ```y=0.4945x-0.1538```. I guess you need to check what is the expected output once more

Comment: @KadenDavila `0.429` is the wrong answer, and `0.4945` is the correct one, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear+regression+%7B+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7+%7D) for verification.

Comment: @risingStark The *slope* of the linear best fit is invariant to translations of the X axis, so shifting the range from `[0, s-1]` to `[1, s]` does not change the final result.

Comment: @dxiv I completely agree. I thought this could be the problem since there was nothing else wrong with code. But turns out there was no problem even with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know the answer before you start.  I plugged your values into a [regression calculator](https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/regression/default.aspx) and got this answer:

```
ŷ = 0.49451*x + 0.34066
```

I know you can only write C.  Kotlin is a Java-like language that might help you structure what you're doing.  These Kotlin functions give the required result:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/regression/default.aspx
    // ŷ = 0.49451X + 0.34066
    val x = arrayOf(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0)
    val y = arrayOf(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0)
    println(regression(x, y))
}

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524137/having-problems-with-my-function-in-c-trying-to-calculate-a-regression-slope-usi
 */
fun regression(x: Array<Double>, y: Array<Double>): Pair<Double, Double> {
    require(x.size == y.size)
    val n = x.size
    val xbar = x.average()
    val ybar = y.average()
    val sumXX = x.fold(0.0) { sum, v -> sum + v*v } - n*xbar*xbar
    val sumXY = x.zip(y) { p, q -> p*q }.fold(0.0) {  sum, v -> sum + v } - n*xbar*ybar
    val b = sumXY/sumXX
    val a = ybar - b*xbar
    return Pair(a, b)
}
```

Here's the output:

```
(0.34065934065934034, 0.4945054945054945)
```

Read about the functional methods zip, fold, etc. to see what they do.  These are general functional programming ideas that you can apply to your C code.  For example, you could pass a C function pointer to a zip or fold function to perform the transformation on array of values.

I'd recommend that you decompose your function into something more readable and test each one individually.